# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid view on my page and I want to export it to the Excel Sheet,
Below is the code I had written to do this task, here I am already passing the dataset to the method to bind the grid and `btnExcelExport` is the button which will export the Grid Content in to Excel Sheet :-

```
private void BindGridView(DataSet ds)
{
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GVUserReport.DataSource = ds;
            GVUserReport.DataBind();
            btnExcelExport.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}

protected void btnExcelExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=FileName.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    GVUserReport.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();
}

public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    return;
}
```

Now when I am debugging I found that the grid is binded sucessfully but when trying to export it to Excel, I'm getting this error:

> "Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message
>   received from the server could not be parsed."

Answer (score 150, accepted):

I fixed this issue. As I'm using `UpdatePanel`, I added below code in the `Page_Load` event of the page and it worked for me:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
  scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.btnExcelExport);
  //Further code goes here....
}
```

Comment: @ShivaPareek it should work any way, but if it doesn't place a ScriptManagerProxy and use that!

Comment: I've used this approach and the whole page is reload. IsPostBackProperty = false which results in not firing the event for the export ? What may be the issue ?

Comment: @KrishnaTiwari I added RegisterPostBackControl to Page_Load and PostBackTrigger to my UpdatePanel. The error disappeared but it now reloads my page. My button is inside UpdatePanel with Conditional mode & ChildrenAsTriggers... No Response.Write in the code behind. what to do?

Comment: Update Panel was the issue for me, I couldn't access the script manager, and I was able to remove update panel

Comment: Works for me, thank you. Is anyone has an explaination why this piece of code is required ?

Comment: This is simplified vb syntax of above code.        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl([GrdFiles_controlname])

Comment: +1 Works great.  Also I recommend debugging to ensure that those lines are actually hit on execution.  In our case we used `Page_PreRender` to register the control, but the method name was incorrectly spelt as `Pre_Render` so the method was never actually being invoked.  A stupid mistake but was much harder to spot than it should have been as the ASP.Net error was deep within the business logic which misguided us.

Comment: I resolved this error by removing the Response.Write code from the code behind which was breaking the AJAX script http://dotnetdebug.net/2006/12/28/syswebformspagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception/

Answer (score 19):

In my case, the problem was caused by some **Response.Write** commands at **Master Page** of the website (code behind). They were there only for debugging purposes (that's not the best way, I know)...

Comment: had same problem.. some debug response write stopped update of cities dropdown after country selected.

Answer (score 11):

I added the control to the `Triggers` tag in the update panel:

```
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="exportLinkButton" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This way the exportLinkButton will trigger the UpdatePanel to update.
More info [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers).

Answer (score 7):

1- **Never** use Response.Write.

2- I put the code below after create (not in Page_Load) a LinkButton (dynamically) and solved my problem:

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(lblbtndoc1);
```

Comment: I suppose the better approach to ad-hoc response writes would be to enable trace on the page you wish to debug and use Trace.Write.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error, then I tried **`<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="xyz"/>`** instead of **AsyncPostBackTrigger** .This worked for me. It is because we don't want a partial postback.

Answer (score 5):

For my VB.Net Friends -

```
Dim scriptManager As ScriptManager = scriptManager.GetCurrent(Me.Page)
scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(Me.YourButtonNameHere)
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to you PageLoad and it will solve your problem:

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.lblbtndoc1);
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11221536/641833) worked for me too, but with an addition (below).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
  scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.btnExcelExport);
  //Further code goes here....
}
```

I was registering a script on my button to click on another button after its event was finished processing. In order for it to work, I had to remove the other button from the Update Panel (just in case somebody faces the same problem).

Answer (score 1):

Before doing all this please check if you have given `asp:LinkButton ID` is same as `asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID`. If its not, the page going to through the same error

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was setting aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys to a high value on appSettings tag on the inetpub VirtualDirectories\443\web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="100000" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```