# button to download csv from server side

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm trying to create a download button that creates a csv file that's filled with data from a data table.  I'm trying to do this on the server side (in hopes of making this button work for chrome/ie/firefox etc) and nothing seems to happen and I can't seem to see why.

```
protected void downloadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.csv");
        Response.Write("blahblahblah");
        Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Show the relevant part of your page markup.  Specifically the button that is linked to this event

Comment: <asp:Button ID="downloadBtn" Text="Export Table to CSV" OnClick="downloadBtn_Click" runat="server" />

Answer (score 2):

So here's what I needed to add to fix my issue.  I was using an UpdatePanel for my download button and thus I needed to add the following lines onto my Page_Load on the server side.

```
    ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
    scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.downloadBtn);
```

More info can be found here:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221033/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-the-message-received-from-t)

This solved my "downloading user generated data on IE/Firefox/Chrome" issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are presenting an `<input type="button">` on your page then your method probably isn't even getting called because a button does not submit a form or make a request to the server by default.

In this example, all three elements will download Test.csv:

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="downloadForm" method="get" action="/downloads/Test.csv">
<input type="button" value="Get File" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('downloadForm').submit()">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<a href="/downloads/Test.csv">Test.csv</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If this isn't the problem then I think a little more code and/or detail may need to be provided to give you a better answer.

Comment: The method does get called.  I tried putting a try/catch statement and I'm getting this exception: "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack"