# Download excel file onclick, "The message received from the server could not be parsed"

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want to do an onclick function that downloads an excel file that is also created when a user clicks a button, so I found this function that I am using for the onclick

```
        public void CreateExcel(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        DataTable dt;
        dt = Database.Get_All_Approval_Table_Grouped            
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=example.xls";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        string tab = "";
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
            tab = "\t";
        }
        Response.Write("\n");
        int i;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            tab = "";
            for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
                tab = "\t";
            }
            Response.Write("\n");
        }
        Response.End();
    }
```

The following is the response I receive:

```
Line: 885
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.
```

Comment: Also, is that the correct content type? It's not an Excel file - it's tab-delimited text.

Comment: what is the file ext of the excel is it .csv or xls
`Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";` should work if not try the following 
`Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";` also why not put your `AddHeader` section something like the following 
`Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=e1.xls");`

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you not not downloading an Excel file, you're serving an ASP.net WebForms page.

You are [modifying the response out from under WebForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221033/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-the-message-received-from-t).

### Also, that's not Excel

Even if you solved the problem (by using an .ashx handler to serve raw content), Excel will then reject it.

Your server is indicating that the **Content-Type** is `application/vnd.ms-excel`:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
```

Except that it ***isn't*** an Excel file. When Excel tries to unzip the `.xlsx` file, it will fail with a security warning that the content does not match the indicated type.