# Error in UpdatePanel: Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I use a `UpdatePanel` with a Gridview in it. A Timer is checking some things in the Gridview. In the Gridview I generate a column for viewing an upload:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zeichnung" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
```

Code behind:

```
 ImageButton ibtn = new ImageButton();
 ibtn.CommandArgument = Upload;
 ibtn.Click += btn_clicked;
 ibtn.ImageUrl = "~/images/download.png";
 ibtn.ToolTip = "Zeichnung öffnen";
 gvr.Cells[20].Controls.Add(ibtn);
```

Clicking the button start the download:

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;Filename=" + Upload);
Response.TransmitFile(Page.MapPath("App_data/OPL/Upload/" + Upload));
Response.End();
```

All worked fine until I put the gridview into the UpdatePanel. Now it throws the error:

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

I tried to replace the `Response.End()` with `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` but nothing changed.

As written here ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221033/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-the-message-received-from-t)) its a problem of the postback. The solution seems to be

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.btnExcelExport);
//Further code goes here....
}
```

But I cannot add this code because the button is generated and not given in the gridview. I tried to add `scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.btn_Upload);` but he is not finding the button.

How can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to register the gridview (as a whole) as the postback control.`ScriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.gvr);`