# Using LinkButton inside GridView and UpdatePanel getting 0x800a139e error

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, imagebutton, asplinkbutton

I use a `Gridview` inside an `UpdatePanel`. In that `Gridview` I use a `LinkButton` (I have the same problem with an `imageButton`) for the `CommandArgument` and try to download a pdf file when the user clicks.

It was tricky to get the Button running in that `UpdatePanel` but all seems fine. The user clicks the Button and I get the correct ID with the `CommandArgument`. With this ID I try to `Response` the pdf file but getting the error:

> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.

The pdf file is on the server, with an button outside the `UpdatePanel` I get the right pdf file. So what to I have to change to get this inside the `UpdatePanel` running? Thanks

Gridview:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Fehlermeldung" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' OnClick="Fehlermeldung_Click1">
                     <asp:Image ID="Fehler" ImageUrl="~/images/fehlermeldung.png" ToolTip="Fehlermeldung anzeigen" runat="server" />
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Fehlermeldung_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument;

            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;Filename=Fehlermeldung_" + id + ".pdf");
            Response.TransmitFile(Page.MapPath(@"App_Data\Fehlermeldung_" + id + ".pdf"));
            Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `Fehlermeldung` link button is contained inside `TemplateField`, hence you cannot directly reference it like normal `LinkButton` does.

You should handle `RowDataBound` event of the `GridView` to find the link button by its control name and put button postback triggers programmatically there using `RegisterPostBackControl()` (`GridViewName` is your grid view ID):

**ASPX Markup**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewName" OnRowDataBound="GridViewName_RowDataBound" runat="server" ...>
    <%-- gridview contents --%>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void GridViewName_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // find link button first
        LinkButton btn = e.Row.FindControl("Fehlermeldung") as LinkButton;

        // use postback trigger assignment
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(btn);
    }
}
```

Reference:

[Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221033/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-the-message-received-from-t)